# (NASM) How can i set memory value using GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, nasm

I have a simple NASM code like below. I want to set the value 43 (which is the +3 offset in `trx` array) to value `99`.

```
section .data
    trx db 25,21,17,43

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov [trx+3], byte 99

last:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

When i debug and the _start function passed, it works. The value `43` changed to `99`.

```
(gdb) i var
All defined variables:

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00000000006000c4  trx
0x00000000006000c8  __bss_start
0x00000000006000c8  _edata
0x00000000006000c8  _end
(gdb) x/4b &trx
0x6000c4:   25  21  17  43
(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b0
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/hexdemsion/Desktop/asm/exec 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004000b0 in _start ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00000000004000b8 in last ()
(gdb) x/4b &trx
0x6000c4:   25  21  17  99
```

Now how can i set that value directly in GDB ? I have tried this command in GDB, but still doesn't work.

```
(gdb) set 0x00000000006000c4+3 = 99
Left operand of assignment is not an lvalue.
(gdb) set {int}0x00000000006000c4+3 = 99
Left operand of assignment is not an lvalue.
(gdb) set {b}0x00000000006000c4+3 = 99
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

For addition, i don't provide any debug information in assemble time.

```
nasm -f elf64 -o obj.o source.asm; ld -o exec obj.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it; use `set {char}(0x00000000006000c4+3) = 99`.

Here's a more detailed explanation:

In gdb's `set` statement, the expression to the left of the `=` can be a convenience variable, or a register name, or an *lvalue* corresponding to  some object in the target.

An lvalue is an object that has an address, a type, and is assignable.

A literal or computed address such as `0x00000000006000c4` or `0x00000000006000c4+3` isn't an lvalue, but you can cast it to an lvalue using `*(type *)(0x00000000006000c4+3)` or `{type}(0x00000000006000c4+3)`.

Gdb knows about C primitive types, plus whatever types the executable and libraries you're debugging may contain in their symbol tables or debug sections. In your case, since you want to set a byte, you'd use C's *char* type.

```
(gdb) x/4b &trx
0x6000c4:   25  21  17  43
(gdb) set {char}(0x00000000006000c4+3) = 99
(gdb) x/4b &trx
0x6000c4:   25  21  17  99
```

Comment: ```(gdb) set {char}(0x00000000006000c4+3) = 99
Cannot access memory at address 0x6000c7```

Comment: still doesn't work sir. i am debugging binary from NASM, not C.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the `Cannot access memory at address 0x6000c7` error. After you get this error, does the `x/4b &trx` command succeed or fail?